# In QTP (12.51) keyword view , how to edit the function call details?

Tags: automation, qtp

[image]After add function call in keyword view, I want to edit  this function call details.

How will edit this function call details ?

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot is in the keyword view, not the expert view.
To move to the expert view choose **View ⇒ Editor** and edit your script.

Comment: you are right. Thanks. Please say in keyword view, how to edit function steps?

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want to add parameters to the function call ?

you can double click on the value column for that function call line and it will show different parameters it can take and then you can add your parameter values

[Parameters in keyword view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLm4l.png)

A basic overview of QTP keyword view is given in below link
http://www.softwaretestingclass.com/brief-overview-of-keyword-view-uftqtp-training-tutorial-11/

If you wanted to make customized functions I would suggest you to use the expert view and seperate function libraries

Let us know if you were looking for something else in answer.

Comment: Thanks for reply. yes, after double click it's showing different parameters option.
But I want to change "operation" . So,is their any option or click event to open step generator window of this function call ?

Comment: No, We can only EDIT parameters for the function call and not the name of the function.

To change the operation value i.e name of the function itself, you will have to insert new step and add a new function call and delete the old one.

Note - I have checked and used till QTP 10, So I am note sure for other   (future) versions but I guess there won't any such option and if it would have been HP would have made it easy to find like by right clicking, or double clicking step or by giving a menu option for editing step.